# How to place sequenced number in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a question.

Suppose I have table A containing 15 items in 15 rows and 1 column (column name: item_name), as shown in the attached picture.

[image]

And then there's table B containing the names of 5 people numbered from 1 to 5

[image] (column: Number, Name).

Each item on table A must be distributed to the people in table B, each person gets 5items, the rule is person number 1 gets the 1st 5items from the top, person number 2 gets the 2nd 5items and so on until person number 3.

Is there any possibility to assign 5 number 1s for the first 5 items on table A, and then 5 number 2s for the next 5 items and so on, so that I can join the 2 tables using numbers so that I know who gets which items?
Result that I  was hoping would be like the attached picture.

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data in table form and expected results

Comment: You probably either want to have another column in table A with the assigned person if the relationship is always a many to 1 OR have a 3rd table that is a joining table with 2 columns if you can have a many to many relationship.

Comment: Do you have a number in `A` too? And what specific DBMS is this aimed at?

Comment: I have attached some pictures in order to help point out my objective. The main point is i'm trying to find a way to place 5 number 1s, 5 number 2s and 5 number 3s in table A,so i can join it with table B to assign the people to the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NTILE`

```
declare @value int = (select COUNT(*) from tableA) / 5

select
    *
from
(
   select
       Item_Name,
       NTILE(@value) over (order by Item_Name) nr
   from tableA
) tbl
join tableB on tableB.Number = tbl.nr
```

Comment: Thank you @Magnus and guys for your help! Really appreciate it!